# Patching Magento / Errors

Tags: patches

If there is an error when applying a patch such as:

"1 out of 1 hunk FAILED"

which only applies to one or two particular files, will the rest of the files be patched successfully?

Or will the entire patch fail and each file revert to their original state if there is a error just effecting one or two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire patch will fail, so you have to ensure that all files can be patched successfully.

You should see "Patch was applied/reverted successfully." at the end of the console output. If not, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen, if your files have the wrong file ending.

If this is your problem `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;` helps