# MageReport scan status Unknown after applying patch SUPEE-5344 successfully

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, security, patches

I applied patch `SUPEE-5344` successfully for my Magento 1.9.1.0 website. But when i go to [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com) and scan my site I still get status `Unknown` for `Security patch 5344 (Shoplift)`?

Comment: Welcome to magento.stackexchange.com. This question has been asked before, see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/error-patch-cant-be-applied-supee-5344-hunk-errors

Comment: You're pretty late with patching with SUPEE-5344. Please make sure you applied all other patches in the order they were released.

Comment: @Anna Völkl So if i understand wright i have to download Magento version (1.9.1.0) from [Magento.com](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and upload/overwrite those concerning files. After patch again..?

Comment: @Anna Völkl i update my question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yep, try to replace the files with the standard installation. The best way is to run a git diff afterwards and check what has changed.

Comment: Ok now its saying `Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.` But if I scan my site at [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com), it still give status 'unknown'. Do you know why?